# Saving images (multer) on an Express.js server on Vercel

Tags: node.js, express, file-upload, vercel

For context: the project is originally about creating Loyalty Cards thorigh Google Wallet API.

**GOAL**: I need to save incoming images from the client on the Vercel server, and use them through 'path/to/image'.

The code structure is like this on the Vercel server:

server(root)/

```
├── src/app.ts ...
├── uploads/
├── package.json
├── ...
```

The problem is that images are not generating on the Vercel server I've deployed. I think it is because of incorrect config of vercel.json file.

- ***vercel.json***

```
    "version": 2,
    "builds": [
        {
            "src": "src/app.ts",
            "use": "@vercel/node"
        }
    ],
    "routes": [
        {
            "src": "uploads/(.*)",
            "dest": "uploads/$1"
        },
        {
            "src": "/(.*)",
            "dest": "src/app.ts"
        }
    ]
}
```

Multer middleware is used for handling 'multipart' content.
I am going to leave essential code in parts, so you may understand what is happening.

- **app.ts**

```
    app.use('/uploads', express.static('uploads'))
    app.use('/loyalty', getLoyaltyRoutes())
```

- **loyalty.ts** (router) ***multer setup***

```
    const storage = multer.diskStorage({
        destination: (req, file, cb) => {
            cb(null, 'uploads/')
        },
        filename: (req, file, cb) => {
            cb(
                null,
                file.fieldname + '-' + Date.now() + path.extname(file.originalname),
            )
        },
    })
    
    const upload = multer({
        storage: storage,
        fileFilter: (req, file, cb) => {
            console.log('Processing file:', file)
            cb(null, true)
        },
    })
    
    export const getLoyaltyRoutes = () => {
        const router = Router()
    
        ...
    
        router.post(
            '/create-jwt-object',
            upload.fields([
                { name: 'googlePayLogoImage', maxCount: 1 },
                { name: 'googlePayHeroImage', maxCount: 1 },
            ]),
            async (req: Request<{}, {}, TReqBody>, res: Response) => {
    
                const { googlePayLogoImage, googlePayHeroImage } =
                    req.files as TFile
    
                    // export type TFile = {
                          googlePayLogoImage: Express.Multer.File[]
                          googlePayHeroImage: Express.Multer.File[]
                       }
    
                const pass = await new DemoLoyalty().createJwtNewObjects(
                    issuerId,
                    classId,
                    objectId,
                    req.body,
                    googlePayLogoImage[0].filename,
                    googlePayHeroImage[0].filename,
                )
    
                res.json(pass)
            },
        )
    
        return router
    }
```

**fileFilter** Vercel log:

```
Processing file: {
  fieldname: 'googlePayLogoImage',
  originalname: 'googlePayLogoImage.png',
  encoding: '7bit',
  mimetype: 'image/png'
}
```

Images do get processed on the Vercel server, but I don't understand why static files are not being generated on the Vercel server.
I am feeling cornered, but I still am going to keep searching for solution. Thanks in advance!